# SpriteKit Scene Transition XCode 7

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

What is wrong with my code here? I am trying to transition from GameScene to ActionScene. In the simulator there is no response to the touch on sprite. Please Help!!

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {
    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        /* Setup your scene here */
        let sprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"Spaceship")

        sprite.xScale = 0.5
        sprite.yScale = 0.5
        sprite.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))


        self.addChild(sprite)
    }

    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        /* Called when a touch begins */

        for touch in touches {
            let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
            let touchedNode = nodeAtPoint(location)

            if touchedNode.name == "sprite" {
                let transition = SKTransition.revealWithDirection(.Down, duration: 0.5)

                let ActionScene = GameScene(size:scene!.size)

                ActionScene.scaleMode = .AspectFill

                scene?.view?.presentScene(ActionScene, transition: transition)
            }


        }
    }

    override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
    /* Called before each frame is rendered */
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You initialised your `ActionScene` wrong. If you want to transition to ActionScene, you cannot initialise GameScene (because I am assuming you are already on GameScene and are trying to transition to actionScene). So change this code

```
let actionScene = GameScene(size:scene!.size)
```

to this

```
let actionScene = ActionScene(size:scene!.size)
```

Comment: I am trying to transition to Action scene. Switching that did not work because there is no scene: actionScene, and I can't use  *  let ActionScene = ActionScene  * because it gives me an error. @Dieblitzen

Comment: So you haven't created an ActionScene? If you haven't created a scene then how do you hope to transition to it? I suggest you create a new file called ActionScene which is a subclass of SKScene so that you can transition to it.